# Haskell OpenGL: Transparency not working

Tags: opengl, haskell, transparency, rgba

I am making a very simple OpenGL application with Haskell, just making some polygons appear at the moment.  My main function looks like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    (pname, _) <- getArgsAndInitialize
    createWindow $ "Haskellisa"
    initialDisplayMode $= [RGBAMode, WithAlphaComponent]
    displayCallback $= display
    mainLoop
```

my 'display' function draws some triangles and sets the colors using a Color4 that has randomly generated RGBA values that are `GLfloats` between 0.0 and 1.0.  Everything works but there is no transparency, overlapping polygons don't blend their colors.

I am drawing triangles using this function:

```
drawTri :: Tri Float -> Color4 GLfloat -> IO ()
drawTri ((x1,y1), (x2,y2), (x3,y3)) col = do
    renderPrimitive Triangles $ do
        color col
        vertex $ (Vertex3 (x1 :: GLfloat) (y1 :: GLfloat) 0)
        vertex $ (Vertex3 (x2 :: GLfloat) (y2 :: GLfloat) 0)
        vertex $ (Vertex3 (x3 :: GLfloat) (y3 :: GLfloat) 0)
```

Why isn't my transparency working here?

Comment: What is the depth buffer comparison? If you reject pixels with equal Z, and they all are at the same depth, no overlapping pixels will be rendered.

Comment: `WithAlphaComponent` enables `GL_BLEND`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Im assuming `[RGBAMode, WithAlphaComponent]` is just to set the bit depth*

I'm not sure how it's done in Haskell, but you have to call `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);` and `glEnable( GL_BLEND );`. You will also have to draw your transparent faces back to front.

More on that here: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting

Comment: It worked!  Haskell Translation:
`blend $= Enabled' and `blendFunc $= (SrcAlpha, OneMinusSrcAlpha)`

Comment: Also I had no idea why I was setting `[RGBAMode, WithAlphaComponent]` it was just a guess, I removed it and everything still works as I wanted it.

Answer (score 3):

Just add:

```
blend $= Enabled >>
blendFunc $= (SrcAlpha, OneMinusSrcAlpha) >>
```

to your display function.

It worked for me! :)